# Download streaming link of video from google drive in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

Because of my bad English, i will give you detail in example so you guys can understand my question and help me :(

For example, i wanna download video from this :

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zj9fZgMGr7dXl3Z3VxSGRadU0/view

Using Chrome DevTool, Network Panel, i catch the request
[image]

And the "Request URL" as show in Chrom DevTool, is the streaming link that i wanna get

My question is : Is there a way to get this "Request URL" without open in browser ? I try to using C# and google drive rest API but after research for a while, i don't know what should i do :(. 
All i done is listing all files stores in my drive by follow this guide. But my try to get webcontentlink or webviewlink response null :(

> https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

I'm asking you in C# because i want to be better at this, but if you have good solution in Java or what, please share it and explain it to me :(

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code you need but first you will have to follow the instructions from https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet to create an API key and copy client_secret.json file to your c# solution

For this example, I've used a Winform project app: I retrieve the WebViewLink via google drive API, and then I play the video in winform App

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.Threading;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";


public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UserCredential credential;

    using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }

    // Create Drive API service.
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
 //here is your request file id taken from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zj9fZgMGr7dXl3Z3VxSGRadU0/view
    FilesResource.GetRequest getRequest =  service.Files.Get("0B6zj9fZgMGr7dXl3Z3VxSGRadU0");
    getRequest.Fields = "webViewLink";
    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = getRequest.Execute();
   //here is the video link you wanted
    string sourceURL = file.WebViewLink;

    //play the video in Winform
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(sourceURL);


}

}
```

results screenshot :
[image: results screenshot]

Comment: I will try ! Thanks you so much !